# Is there a known algorithm for simplifying a boolean expression with number comparisons?

Tags: algorithm, compiler-optimization, boolean-algebra

For example, if I have the expression `(A > 5) && (A == 6)`,
that expression can be simplified to just `(A == 6)`, and still have the same behavior for A ∈ ℤ.

I also need it to work with multiple variables, so for instance `((B > 2) && (C == 2)) || ((B > 2) && (C < 2))` should simplify to `(B > 2) && (C < 3)`.

I won't need to compare two unknowns, only unknowns and numbers, and I only need it to work with the operators `<`, `>`, and `==` for numbers, and `&&` and `||` for expressions (`&&` being AND and `||` being OR, of course). All unknowns are integers.

Is there any algorithm that takes such an expression and returns an expression with equal behavior and a minimal amount of operators?

(in my specific case, `||` operators are preferred over `&&`)

Comment: This is at least as hard computationally as minimizing a Boolean function, which is not only NP-hard but NP-with-oracle-access-to-NP--hard. I think many of the (exponential-time) algorithms can be generalized, though.

Comment: The part of a compiler that does this sort of thing is called "peephole optimization".  You can google that.  It's a big topic.  It's not a general algorithm, since that's impractical.  It works by matching specific patterns that are then replaced with more efficient ones.  A good compiler might have 1000 patterns that it will match and optimize.

Comment: gcc does it.  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9PPaTKMPz .  One way this can be done is _abstract  interpretation_.  You'll find many references with a google search.  As @DavidEisenstat says,  you can't hope for a true minimum, but you asked for _minimal_, which is achievable for a given abstract domain choice.

Comment: The reason I think there’s a general algorithm out there is because of the small number of operators. When there is only one unknown variable, each comparison can be thought about as defining a section on the number-line, and each boolean expression can be thought about as overlapping or unionizing these sections. The result is then quite easy to find the minimum expression for, because there is no NOT operator or such. I’m pretty sure the problem with more variables can be solved with the same geometrical thinking in multiple dimensions, but I have a hard time wrapping my head around that.

Comment: You have described an abstract domain for abstract interpretation. That's the "general algorithm."

Comment: Sorry, it's _clang_ that removes the unneeded comparison (link above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a *slow* dynamic programming algorithm along the lines that you were thinking of.

```py
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from heapq import heappop, heappush
from itertools import product
from math import inf

# Constructors for Boolean expressions. False and True are also accepted.
Lt = namedtuple("Lt", ["lhs", "rhs"])
Eq = namedtuple("Eq", ["lhs", "rhs"])
Gt = namedtuple("Gt", ["lhs", "rhs"])
And = namedtuple("And", ["lhs", "rhs"])
Or = namedtuple("Or", ["lhs", "rhs"])

# Variable names. Arbitrary strings are accepted.
A = "A"
B = "B"
C = "C"

# Example formulas.
first_example = And(Gt(A, 5), Eq(A, 6))
second_example = Or(And(Gt(B, 2), Eq(C, 2)), And(Gt(B, 2), Lt(C, 2)))
third_example = Or(And(Gt(A, 1), Gt(B, 1)), And(Gt(A, 0), Gt(B, 2)))
fourth_example = Or(Lt(A, 6), Gt(A, 5))
fifth_example = Or(And(Eq(A, 2), Gt(C, 2)), And(Eq(B, 2), Lt(C, 2)))

# Returns a map from each variable to the set of values such that the formula
# might evaluate differently for variable = value-1 versus variable = value.
def get_critical_value_sets(formula, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = defaultdict(set)
    if isinstance(formula, bool):
        pass
    elif isinstance(formula, Lt):
        result[formula.lhs].add(formula.rhs)
    elif isinstance(formula, Eq):
        result[formula.lhs].add(formula.rhs)
        result[formula.lhs].add(formula.rhs + 1)
    elif isinstance(formula, Gt):
        result[formula.lhs].add(formula.rhs + 1)
    elif isinstance(formula, (And, Or)):
        get_critical_value_sets(formula.lhs, result)
        get_critical_value_sets(formula.rhs, result)
    else:
        assert False, str(formula)
    return result


# Returns a list of inputs sufficient to compare Boolean combinations of the
# primitives returned by enumerate_useful_primitives.
def enumerate_truth_table_inputs(critical_value_sets):
    variables, value_sets = zip(*critical_value_sets.items())
    return [
        dict(zip(variables, values))
        for values in product(*({-inf} | value_set for value_set in value_sets))
    ]


# Returns both constants and all single comparisons whose critical value set is
# a subset of the given ones.
def enumerate_useful_primitives(critical_value_sets):
    yield False
    yield True
    for variable, value_set in critical_value_sets.items():
        for value in value_set:
            yield Lt(variable, value)
            if value + 1 in value_set:
                yield Eq(variable, value)
            yield Gt(variable, value - 1)


# Evaluates the formula recursively on the given input.
def evaluate(formula, input):
    if isinstance(formula, bool):
        return formula
    elif isinstance(formula, Lt):
        return input[formula.lhs] < formula.rhs
    elif isinstance(formula, Eq):
        return input[formula.lhs] == formula.rhs
    elif isinstance(formula, Gt):
        return input[formula.lhs] > formula.rhs
    elif isinstance(formula, And):
        return evaluate(formula.lhs, input) and evaluate(formula.rhs, input)
    elif isinstance(formula, Or):
        return evaluate(formula.lhs, input) or evaluate(formula.rhs, input)
    else:
        assert False, str(formula)


# Evaluates the formula on the many inputs, packing the values into an integer.
def get_truth_table(formula, inputs):
    truth_table = 0
    for input in inputs:
        truth_table = (truth_table << 1) + evaluate(formula, input)
    return truth_table


# Returns (the number of operations in the formula, the number of Ands).
def get_complexity(formula):
    if isinstance(formula, bool):
        return (0, 0)
    elif isinstance(formula, (Lt, Eq, Gt)):
        return (1, 0)
    elif isinstance(formula, And):
        ops_lhs, ands_lhs = get_complexity(formula.lhs)
        ops_rhs, ands_rhs = get_complexity(formula.rhs)
        return (ops_lhs + 1 + ops_rhs, ands_lhs + 1 + ands_rhs)
    elif isinstance(formula, Or):
        ops_lhs, ands_lhs = get_complexity(formula.lhs)
        ops_rhs, ands_rhs = get_complexity(formula.rhs)
        return (ops_lhs + 1 + ops_rhs, ands_lhs + ands_rhs)
    else:
        assert False, str(formula)


# Formula compared by complexity.
class HeapItem:
    __slots__ = ["_complexity", "formula"]

    def __init__(self, formula):
        self._complexity = get_complexity(formula)
        self.formula = formula

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._complexity < other._complexity

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._complexity <= other._complexity

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._complexity == other._complexity

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._complexity != other._complexity

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._complexity >= other._complexity

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._complexity > other._complexity


# Like heapq.merge except we can add iterables dynamically.
class Merge:
    __slots__ = ["_heap", "_iterable_count"]

    def __init__(self):
        self._heap = []
        self._iterable_count = 0

    def update(self, iterable):
        iterable = iter(iterable)
        try:
            value = next(iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            return
        heappush(self._heap, (value, self._iterable_count, iterable))
        self._iterable_count += 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if not self._heap:
            raise StopIteration
        value, index, iterable = heappop(self._heap)
        try:
            next_value = next(iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            return value
        heappush(self._heap, (next_value, index, iterable))
        return value


class Combinations:
    __slots__ = ["_op", "_formula", "_best_formulas", "_i", "_n"]

    def __init__(self, op, formula, best_formulas):
        self._op = op
        self._formula = formula
        self._best_formulas = best_formulas
        self._i = 0
        self._n = len(best_formulas)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._i >= self._n:
            raise StopIteration
        formula = self._op(self._formula, self._best_formulas[self._i])
        self._i += 1
        return HeapItem(formula)


# Returns the simplest equivalent formula, breaking ties in favor of fewer Ands.
def simplify(target_formula):
    critical_value_sets = get_critical_value_sets(target_formula)
    inputs = enumerate_truth_table_inputs(critical_value_sets)
    target_truth_table = get_truth_table(target_formula, inputs)
    best = {}
    merge = Merge()
    for formula in enumerate_useful_primitives(critical_value_sets):
        merge.update([HeapItem(formula)])
    best_formulas = []
    for item in merge:
        if target_truth_table in best:
            return best[target_truth_table]
        formula = item.formula
        truth_table = get_truth_table(formula, inputs)
        if truth_table in best:
            continue
        n = len(best_formulas)
        for op in [And, Or]:
            merge.update(Combinations(op, formula, best_formulas))
        best[truth_table] = formula
        best_formulas.append(formula)


print(simplify(first_example))
print(simplify(second_example))
print(simplify(third_example))
print(simplify(fourth_example))
print(simplify(fifth_example))
```

Output:

```py
Eq(lhs='A', rhs=6)
And(lhs=Lt(lhs='C', rhs=3), rhs=Gt(lhs='B', rhs=2))
And(lhs=And(lhs=Gt(lhs='B', rhs=1), rhs=Gt(lhs='A', rhs=0)), rhs=Or(lhs=Gt(lhs='B', rhs=2), rhs=Gt(lhs='A', rhs=1)))
True
Or(lhs=And(lhs=Eq(lhs='B', rhs=2), rhs=Lt(lhs='C', rhs=2)), rhs=And(lhs=Gt(lhs='C', rhs=2), rhs=Eq(lhs='A', rhs=2)))
```

Comment: @Spu7Nix you can optimize by combining the truth tables and complexities directly -- more efficient than recomputing from scratch each time, but less clear.

Comment: It seems to run into a problem with the formula `Or(And(Eq(A, 2), Gt(C, 2)), And(Eq(B, 2), Lt(C, 2)))`, where it just fills the heap with millions of items until the computer runs out of memory. Is this a bug, or is it just that inefficient?

Comment: @Spu7Nix it was that inefficient. I upgraded the search to be somewhat less inefficient, such that it can solve your new example, but it's still pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it seems like it's still not efficient enough, as it runs out of memory again if I add just one more variable. Do you have any ideas for how I could make an algorithm that is more scalable? Perhaps one that doesn't use dp? There is another answer in this thread that suggests I try to use ranges, but I have difficulties seeing how it would work in all situations. Maybe I could use your algorithm if there are less than 3 variables and an "imperfect" algorithm for all other formulas?

Comment: @Spu7Nix the implementation is still very wasteful, but the scaling is doubly exponential (complexity squares for each additional variable with an inequality, cubes for each equality), so an efficient (e.g.) C++ port might handle one more variable. The range answer definitely does not work. I'd look into what production compilers are doing.

Comment: I'm using Rust, so I'm about as efficient as it gets language-wise. Another comment mentioned that clang does this, but after some testing, it seems to only do it for simple cases, probably just matching specific cases.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can consider intervals for your variables, for example:

```
(A > 5) && (A == 6)
```

Given you have a variable `A`, set an initial interval for it: `A: [-∞, ∞]`.

Each condition that you read, you can reduce your interval:

```
(A > 5)  sets the interval for A: [6, ∞]
(A == 6) sets the interval for A: [6, 6]
```

For each update on the interval, check if the new condition is possible, for example:

```
(A > 5)  sets the interval for A: [6, ∞]
(A == 5) out of the interval, impossible condition.
```

---

Just another example:

```
((B > 2) && (C == 2)) || ((B > 2) && (C < 2))
```

Initially: `B: [-∞, ∞]` and `C: [-∞, ∞]`.

```
((B > 2) && (C == 2))

(B > 2)  sets the interval for B: [3, ∞]
(C == 2) sets the interval for C: [2, 2]
```

The next condition is attached with `||`, so you add intervals:

```
((B > 2) && (C < 2)) 

(B > 2) sets the interval for B: [3, ∞]
(C < 2) sets the interval for C: [2, 2] U [-∞, 1] = [-∞, 2]
```

Comment: The thing this doesn't take into account is that a variable's interval might depend on the value of another value, for example for the expression `((A > 1) && (B > 1)) || ((A > 0) && (B > 2))`, the interval of one variable can't be defined because it depends on the other variable (this example can't really be simplified, so it might be redundant, but still)

Comment: @Spu7Nix you could recursively simplify each condition separated by the ```||``` operator

Comment: How would your method solve a case like this: `((A == 2) || (B == 2)) && ((A < 3) || (B > 2))`? (simplifies to `((B == 2) || (A == 2)) || (A < 3)`)